# How to count unique and duplicate in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned two table:

Table1

```
ID      Value

RS-1    10
RS-2    20
RS-6    30
RS-3    40
```

Table2

```
ID2        Ref_ID      status      Date

RS-1       se12tc      accepted    2019-01-01 14:06:46
RS-1       se14xc      pending     2019-01-02 18:11:26
RS-1       se01df      shipped     2019-01-01 13:16:34
RS-6       se73zc      reject      2019-01-03 11:19:20
RS-6       sy01tc      pending     2019-01-03 19:17:16
RS-2       se56vc      accepted    2019-02-02 10:06:02
RS-2       se00tc      reject      2019-02-02 12:02:16
RS-2       se88ee      pending     2019-02-03 12:23:47
RS-3       se13xf      accepted    2019-01-01 18:36:11
```

By utilizing the above two tables I need to derive to the output at mentioned in the format.

Where,

- `Month` - Derived from the `Date` column
- `Distinct_ID>1count` - Count of duplicate `ID` in table two for the
  same `Month`
- `Total_ID>1count` - Sum of Total those `ID` which occurs more than 1
  time in table2 one for the same `Month`
- `1count` - the sum of those `ID` which occurs only one time in table2 for
  the same `Month`

Output:

```
Month      Distinct_ID>1count  Total_ID>1count            1count   Sum_Value
Jan-2019      2                      5                       1        50
Feb-2019      1                      3                       0        50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First group by month and id2 to get the counts of each id2 and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  t.month,
  sum(t.counter > 1) `Distinct_ID>1count`,
  sum(case when t.counter > 1 then counter else 0 end) `Total_ID>1count`,
  sum(t.counter = 1) `1count`
from (
  select 
    date_format(date, '%Y%m') morder, 
    date_format(date, '%b-%Y') month, 
    id2, 
    count(*) counter 
  from table2
  group by morder, month, id2
)t
group by t.morder, t.month
order by t.morder
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCzNEfiF9ZU6CDyTzVzWvg/0).
Results:

```
| month    | Distinct_ID>1count | Total_ID>1count | 1count |
| -------- | ------------------ | --------------- | ------ |
| Jan-2019 | 2                  | 5               | 1      |
| Feb-2019 | 1                  | 3               | 0      |
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but i missed to add the `Value` part for which I am joining these two tables, please help me understand where should i put the join condition to get the `Value` in output.

Comment: This answers the question as you posted it. If there is a new requirement post a new question.

Comment: @user9211845 keep in mind that `count(*)` counts `NULL` values aswell.. From the example data and expected result its not clear if you need `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(<column/expression>)` to not count `NULL` values..